# Jenkins using PowerShell Azure Modules failing to run

Tags: azure, powershell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, azure-powershell

I have a bit of a strange one here.

I have written a PowerShell script to pull Azure blob storage objects which when I run manually via the console works absolutely fine. However if i run it from jenkins, it calls the PowerShell function, starts running through it but fails when using the az.storage function **Get-azstorageblobcontent**.

The errors seem to be things like "Couldn't connect" or "Retry count exceeded" etc. I am unable to use the -debug switch as it says its interactive.

I have tested by including the access token inside the script, eliminating jenkins from handling the secrets but i get the same issue.

Jenkins is running the latest version, latest PowerShell plugin and latest version of java. it is also calling the 64 bit powershell session as expected.
I am also aware that there is a Jenkins Blob storage plugin however due to the amount of additional work that is required, it makes a lot more sense i use the PowerShell Modules inside a PowerShell Script to run this.

I would really appreciate if anyone has any ideas about this please, It has been driving me nuts for weeks.

Many Thanks

Comment: It looks like Jenkins is not able to reach Azure endpoint. Check ports and network connectivity (may be the storage account is IP restricted?).

Comment: Hello, If I run the powershell script manually on the Jenkins server, it works fine. It is behind a proxy but the first few Azure commands work i.e. get list of containers. Its only when I actually go to pull the blob content it fails. So I am not sure if this is network related. Or if it is, I am unsure how to determine this.

Comment: at least you can telnet blob host from jenkins server